# Ionic для начиначинающих

Tags: android, ios, ionic, ionicframework, ionic2

почитал про Ionic и очень заинтересовался им.
кто работает с ним, подскажите с чего вообще начать? где можно посмотреть видео или почитать (желательно на русском). разработка сразу для ios и android

какую IDE использовать для работы с ним лучше?
может какой туториал есть для начинающих "чайников" так сказать

Comment: Загляни [сюда](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/mo-ionic-framework-app/index.html)

Comment: всё бы хорошо, но там с маком + только ios